# Getting the maximum matches from database using select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use a SELECT statement to get number of matches from my database that has matches more than 0, but I also want to just get the maximum matches. So if there are matches of 1,2, and 3, I just want to matches of 3. After I added in the part "AND  'matches' = MAX( 'matches' )", it stopped getting results, for some reason. It was getting results before I added it. I'm wondering what I did wrong, and how to fix it. Thanks.

```
SELECT input, response, 
( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + 
( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + 
( input LIKE  '% here %' ) 
AS  'matches'
FROM allData
HAVING  `matches` > 0
AND  'matches' = MAX( 'matches' )
```

Comment: Before getting the matches you can not know which is the max so it is normal if this is not working. I would get all the matches grouped by the matches and then sort by count or find the max in that group and then select the needed fields in them.

Comment: @CntkCtn Please try answering.

Comment: To answer I need the DB and make tests to be sure that I give the correct answer perfectly and I do not have it at the moment. I will keep it as a comment.

Comment: @CntkCtn Just give me an example code, using my example. If it works, it works. If it doesn't, at least you tried.

Comment: @CntkCtn ...Isn't that the exact same code as my example? I don't see any differences.

Comment: It was a mistake! I hit the enter button in comment box.

Comment: You can try to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for future questions. It would be much way better for everybody.

Comment: @CntkCtn I knew that there was phpFiddle, but I didn't know there was a sqlfiddle too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged mysql in your question.  This is a bit unfortunate, because the question can be answered more cleanly for almost any other relational database popular today than it can be for MySQL.  Nevertheless, with MySQL you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  input,
  response, 
    ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + 
    ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + 
    ( input LIKE  '% here %' ) 
    AS  matches
FROM allData
HAVING  matches > 0
  AND matches = (
      SELECT MAX(
        ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + 
        ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + 
        ( input LIKE  '% here %' ) )
      FROM allData
    )
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that if it finds 2 hits of the same word, the matches increases by 2 instead of one?

Comment: Hi @jessica, see my edited answer. You can use the same technique in John's query.

Comment: @jessica, Thorsten's is a pretty clever way to count matches of the same pattern.  Do note, however, that in that regard and in others you have an issue with the spaces on either side of the `LIKE` patterns.  They do ensure that you match only complete words, but they also *prevent* you from matching words that are immediately preceded or immediately followed by punctuation.  With respect to counting, they will interfere with counting doubled words (`' you you are are here here '`).

Comment: John. Actually, I just realize that it would be better if it matches that backward. So, for example, if the input is "you you you", it would try to find matches of string with matches of 3 yous and count that as 3 matches, then matches of 2 yous, and count that as 2 yous, and finally matches of 1 yous as 1 yous. Is that doable?

Comment: @jessica, yes, you could apply a correction to Thorsten's count via a technique along the lines you describe.  Read up on SQL `CASE` expressions for one way to accomplish it.  This is growing into a pretty horrible query, though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` to get the best record only:

```
SELECT input, response, 
( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + 
( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + 
( input LIKE  '% here %' ) 
AS  matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches > 0
ORDER BY matches DESC LIMIT 1;
```

In case of a tie you would get only one random best record though. If you want all, then go with John Bollinger's answer.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ece1/3.

---

If you want to count multiple matches, use some math: remove the search string from input and count how often its length was removed:

```
SELECT input, response, 
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' you ', ''))) / length(' you ')) +
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' are ', ''))) / length(' are ')) +
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' here ', ''))) / length(' here '))
  AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches > 0
ORDER BY matches DESC LIMIT 1;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f680b/3.

And one more fiddle to show how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f680b/1.

---

Here is John's query with the same technique:

```
SELECT input, response, 
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' you ', ''))) / length(' you ')) +
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' are ', ''))) / length(' are ')) +
((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' here ', ''))) / length(' here '))
  AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches > 0
AND matches = 
(
  SELECT MAX(
    ((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' you ', ''))) / length(' you ')) +
    ((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' are ', ''))) / length(' are ')) +
    ((length(input) - length(replace(input, ' here ', ''))) / length(' here '))
  )
  FROM allData
);
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57098/1.

---

As to ' you you you ' you are right; by removing ' you ' from the string I take with it a space needed to find the next ' you '. You can easily circumvent this though by replacing each space with two in `input` before doing the operation. And you may want to add a leading and a trainling space, too. (You may even want to apply `LOWER()` on the string, so as to find 'You' as well as 'you'.)

So replace

```
  FROM allData
```

with

```
FROM 
(
  select 
    replace(concat(' ', input, ' '), ' ', '  ') as input, 
    response
  from allData
) prepared
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that if it finds 2 hits of the same word, the matches increases by 2 instead of one?

Comment: Yes it is. It needs just some math. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: Ah. One of the results returned 1.1667? How is that possible?

Comment: Hey. Can you make one with the same as John's answer, except with the length.replace?

Comment: As to 1.1667: That is 7/6. Obviously the strings were different like `((length(input) - length(replace(input, '1234567', ''))) / length('123456'))`.

Comment: I'm trying to combine yours and John's answer, but it's not working, and is giving me an headache. If you can, please help with that.

Comment: Here you are. You don't have to accept my answer, though. John answered your original question perfectly. How about an upvote instead :-)

Comment: Sure. Here you go. Thanks for your answer. It works and saved me from a lot of headache.

Comment: Actually, I just realize that it would be better if it matches that backward. So, for example, if the input is "you you you", it would try to find matches of string with matches of 3 yous and count that as 3 matches, then matches of 2 yous, and count that as 2 yous, and finally matches of 1 yous as 1 yous. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I see my issue with 'you you you'. I've edited my answer once more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows with the maximum of matches, then one method is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT input, response,
       ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% here %' ) AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches = (SELECT ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% here %' ) as matches
                  FROM allData
                  HAVING `matches` > 0
                  ORDER BY matches DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 )
```

There is, however, another way that uses variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT input, response,
             ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% here %' ) AS matches,
             (@m := if(@m < ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% here %' ),
                       ( input LIKE  '% you %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% are %' ) + ( input LIKE  '% here %' ), 0)
      FROM allData CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m := 0) params
     ) t
WHERE matches = @m;
```

This uses the "feature" that the subquery is evaluated before the outer query, so you can set a value in the subquery and then use it in the outer `where`.

Comment: Unknown column 'matches' in 'field list

Comment: Can you delete the ' quatation marks near the matches in the whole query.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that if it finds 2 hits of the same word, the matches increases by 2 instead of one?